# CRUD operations in a grid inside a parent grid detail template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Here's a sample code from the Kendo Grid Detail Template [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/detailtemplate) on the Telerik website (I've simplified the detail template by removing the tab-strip):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.EmployeeViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(e => e.LastName).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(e => e.Country).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(e => e.City).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(e => e.Title);
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    .Scrollable()
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(5)
        .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "Grid"))
    )
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
)

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
       @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=EmployeeID#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Title("ID").Width(56);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName).Width(190);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(5)
                .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))
            )
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .ToClientTemplate()
        )
</script>
```

I'd like to add a Create button to the child grid (Order grid) inside the template. The problem is that when a new Order is being added, I need to pass the EmployeeID to the controller, but the following does not work, even though it works for the Read action:

```
.Create(create => create.Action("AddOrder", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))
```

How do I pass the EmployeeID to the controller when adding a new item to the grid in the detail template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set an `EmployeeID` value as a parameter in its create transport. Because you will do `POST` request here, the right way to do it is to pass the value as default value of `EmployeeID` of Grid model.

Your inner Grid should have configuration data source like this

```
.DataSource(ds=> ds.Ajax()
                   .PageSize(5)
                   .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#: EmployeeID #" }))
                   .Create(create => create.Action("AddOrder", "Grid"))
                   .Model(model => 
                          {
                              model.Id(f => f.OrderID)
                              model.Field(f => f.EmployeeID).DefaultValue("#: EmployeeID #")
                           })
            )
```

The moment you add new record to server its `EmployeeID` value has been set.

**Note**: EmployeeID will be assigned by `string` value because of this expression `"#= #"`,you should have EmployeeID as `string` type. Or you will get razor error for incompatible type.

Comment: I've tried that too. It doesn't work. By the way, the Read action call is a POST request too, but I pass the EmpolyeeID value as a parameter; and it works.

Comment: For some reason, `#=EmployeeID#` doesn't work inside `DefaultValue("#=EmployeeID#")`.

Comment: It works on my end, have you read the error? Its string type, maybe you have incompatible type. Check your EmployeeID data type of your model, is it int or string type?

Comment: If its not a string type, you better change it to string type

Comment: I'd rather not change the data type. However, it looks like there's no other option. The DefaultValue method should have been smart enough to convert the data type.

Comment: because you are using `razor` and combine with evaluated `javascript function expression` whereas it will result string type no matter what. It should be okay to change data type, as long as you have separated model e.g view model and domain model.